# Using arc4random_uniform to return a both whole and non whole doubles

Tags: swift, arc4random

Using Swift, I am trying to figure out how to use arc4random_uniform to return a number like 37.7. The guidance I must abide by is I must do it in a function, the random double must be between 0 - 300. I have been able to build a function that randomly returns doubles between the range but can't find anything that will lead me to outputting random non whole numbers

```
//function to randomly generate a double number like 105.3
func makeRandDbl() -> Double {
    let randGenerator: Double = Double(arc4random_uniform(301))
    print(randGenerator)

return randGenerator
}

makeRandDb()
```

Comment: If you only need one decimal place, you could do `Double(arc4random_uniform(3001))/10.0`.

Comment: How did you know this was a viable option? This does work.

Comment: It simply generates a number between 0 and 3000, converts that to a double and divides by 10 which gives you a number between 0.0 and 300.0.

Comment: @vacawama Naturally, this limits the number of different values produced to 3000, which may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, OP gave both `37.7` and `105.3` as examples, so maybe they just need a `Double` with 1 decimal place.

Comment: Yes I wanted to find out the ideology behind it so I could apply it using other types. So This does answer my question.

Comment: The point is that this is not a "double." A double is a floating-point number with double-precision. What you want is a *fixed-point* number (having a precise precision to the right of the decimal place). If that's your goal, you should just work in Int and treat it as "tenths." Using Double will introduce error. (For example, 10.1 cannot be expressed precisely as a Double, but 101 tenths can be precisely expressed an an Int.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a `Double` in the range 0.0 to 300.0 (with one digit following the decimal):

```
Double(arc4random_uniform(3001))/10.0
```

You can extend this to more decimal places.  For two decimal places (0.00 to 300.00):

```
Double(arc4random_uniform(30001))/100.0
```

For three decimal places (0.000 to 300.000):

```
Double(arc4random_uniform(300001))/1000.0
```

This has the advantage of being able to actually generate whole values.  In the first case 10% of the numbers will be whole.  In the second case 1% of the numbers will be whole.  And in the third, 0.1% of the numbers will be whole.

Answer (score 2):

This is your function, I believe:

```
extension Double {

/// Generates a random `Double` within `0.0...1.0`
public static func random() -> Double {
    return random(0.0...1.0)
}

/// Generates a random `Double` inside of the closed interval.
public static func random(interval: ClosedInterval<Double>) -> Double {
    return interval.start + (interval.end - interval.start) * (Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max))
}

}
```

Usage example:

```
Double.random(0...300)
```

It is taken from [RandomKit](https://github.com/nvzqz/RandomKit) library - it looks very useful for various purposes.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to convert the result of `arc4random_uniform` to `double`, divide the result by `UInt32.max`, and then multiply the result by 300.

```
let rand = 300 * Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32.max)) / Double(UInt32.max)
```

This would produce a value between 0 and 300, inclusive. The number of possible values that you are going to get is `UInt32.max`.

Comment: this is awesome as well and more along the lines of what my professor is teaching us.